# How do I detect the Connection Type based on the IP address?

Tags: ip, detection

How do I detect the Connection Type based on the IP address?

Connection Type is for example like: Residential, Business, College, Work, Library, etc.

You probably can't detect it directly. But some sites kind of find out from where you are accessing.

You probably can't detect that reliably. But that's not important.

To find out the country based on IP address, I use [MaxMind GeoIP](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) for example.

Is there something similar for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could...

1. do a [reverse-DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) on the IP address
2. extract the domain name
3. use "[whois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois)" to get the owner information
4. guess at the type of entity that owns that address

Not exactly the type of thing you can do in real-time or an every incoming connection, I expect, but with some clever caching and off-line work you might get something functional.